# Permission denied on git repository with Fabric

Tags: python, git, fabric

I'm writing a fab script to do a `git pull` on a remote server, but I get `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).` when fabric runs the command.

If I ssh to the server and then do the pull, it works. (I've already setup the keys on the server, so it doesn't ask for passphrases, etc.)

Here's my fabric task:

```
import fabric.api as fab
def update():
  '''
  update workers code
  '''
  with fab.cd('~/myrepo'):
      # pull changes
      print colors.cyan('Pulling changes...')
      fab.run('git pull origin master')
```

How do I get it to work with Fabric?

**Edit:** My server is a [Google Compute](https://developers.google.com/compute/) instance, and it provides a [gcutil](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/) tool to ssh to the instance. This is the command it runs to connect to the server:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/John/.ssh/google_compute_engine -A -p 22 John@123.456.789.101
```

The script is able to connect to the server AFAICT (it's able to run commands on the server like `cd` and `supervisor` and `git status`), it's just `git pull` that fails.

Comment: Under which user you run task (and thus - git under fabric)? "Permission denied..." for git operation is a symptom of failed authetication

Comment: I'm using the same user for both. My host in fabric is `[John@server]`, and when I ssh, it's as `John@server` as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to edit fabfile like this in order to enable ssh agent fowarding option.

```
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['123.456.789.101']
env.user = 'John'
env.key_filename = '/Users/John/.ssh/google_compute_engine'
env.forward_agent = True

def update():
  '''
  update workers code
  '''
  with cd('~/myrepo'):
      # pull changes
      print colors.cyan('Pulling changes...')
      run('git pull origin master')
```

Comment: Still getting the error with git after specifying the key. It's able to connect to the server (was able to do a `cd` and run `supervisor` commands), it's just `git` that fails.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a misunderstanding. SSH option [-A] mean ssh agent forwarding. So git pull command use [/Users/John/.ssh/google_compute_engine] key . You need to enable env option[env.forward_agent = True] for use ssh agent fowarding.

Comment: Just to clarify, without `-A`, the server is using whatever key it has in its .ssh directory when doing the `git pull` right?

Comment: That's right. When use without `-A` option, then push command use `user@remotehost:~/.ssh/id_rsa`